# Is there a need for at least one edgeSDK on the device to be connected to the internet to create the mesh network?

Tags: mesh-network, edgesdk, edgeengine

Is there a need for at least one edgeSDK on the device to be connected to the internet to create the mesh network? Or will it work even if no devices are connected to the internet?